# How to sort array with name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I am trying to sort array of objects with name.

**Working Snippet:**

```js
const data = [
   {
      "title":"Smart S",
      "tariff_id":"1301"
   },
   {
      "title":"Smart M",
      "tariff_id":"1306"
   },
   {
      "title":"Smart L",
      "tariff_id":"1303"
   },
   {
      "title":"Start",
      "tariff_id":"1304"
   },
   {
      "title":"Smart  6",
      "tariff_id":"1305"
   },
   {
      "title":"Ausland",
      "tariff_id":"888888",
   },
   {
      "title":"Länderzone",
      "tariff_id":"999999",
   }
];

//Filtering the data by removing the unwanted data
const newTariffs = (data || []).filter((tariff) =>
          tariff?.tariff_id != 888888 && tariff?.tariff_id != 999999
);

// Need to sort in this order
const tariffOrder = ["Start", "Smart S", "Smart M", "Smart L", "Smart 6"]; 

//Sort code that have been tried
const sortedTariffs = (newTariffs || []).sort((a, b) =>
    tariffOrder.indexOf(a.title) > tariffOrder.indexOf(b.title) ? 1 : -1
);


console.log("sortedTariffs ", sortedTariffs);
```

From the above data, the requirement is that,

-> Need to remove two items with highest id ie.., `888888` and `999999` (Used filter method)

-> Then need to sort the new filtered array based on the tariff order,

`"Start", "Smart S", "Smart M", "Smart L", "Smart 6"`

**Current Result:**

`[{"title":"Smart  6","tariff_id":"1305"},{"title":"Start","tariff_id":"1304"},{"title":"Smart S","tariff_id":"1301"},{"title":"Smart M","tariff_id":"1306"},{"title":"Smart L","tariff_id":"1303"}]`

**Expected Result:**

`[{"title":"Start","tariff_id":"1304"},{"title":"Smart S","tariff_id":"1301"},{"title":"Smart M","tariff_id":"1306"},{"title":"Smart L","tariff_id":"1303"}, {"title":"Smart  6","tariff_id":"1305"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order like this to get ascending order or sort.

```
var sortedTariffs = newTariffs.sort((a, b) =>
    (a.title < b.title) - (a.title > b.title)
);
```

Comment: Could you please explain little more in detail how this works without providing sort order array?

Answer (score 2):

To sort by title:

```js
const sortedTariffs = (newTariffs || []).sort((a, b) =>
    a.title.localeCompare(b.title)
);
```

`localeCompare` will compare two strings and return -1 or 1, as expected by sort.

### Edit:

After reading again the question, I misread ir. The problem you have is that the string "Smart  6" has 2 spaces instead of 1, so `indexOf()` returns `-1`, and it's placed first

Comment: The above gives result as `[{"title":"Smart  6","tariff_id":"1305"},{"title":"Smart L","tariff_id":"1303"},{"title":"Smart M","tariff_id":"1306"},{"title":"Smart S","tariff_id":"1301"},{"title":"Start","tariff_id":"1304"}]`

Comment: @HelloWorld Sorry, I misread the question. Edited with the problem: `Smart  6` has 2 spaces, so it's not found inside `tariffOrder`